# Android WebView - Works in browser but not WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android, mobile, webview

I am attempting to create an Android game in Javascript, then I planned on putting it into a WebView. The problem is, although my game works 100% in the default Android browser, running it in a WebView seems to break it somehow. I've looked through all of my code and cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is.

I used [this game](http://m.gamesgames.com/game/Space+Sudoku/en_US/index.html) as the "codebase" for my own game, and it faces the same issue.
It loads perfectly in the default Android browser but when you put it into a WebView it will no longer play. Simply copy the above link into a webview and see for yourself.

Note I do have Javascript enabled and the webview is functioning properly.

Perhaps the cache manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com)? You have all the hard work done and works out of the box.

Comment: I have just attempted using Phonegap with the game HTML without success, same problem as with a normal WebView.